# Printing images on EPL Zebra Printer

Tags: php, image, zebra-printers, epl

Ok, so i have a "template.prn" that get's filled with info with a PHP script i made. The PHP generates multiple `FR` for every 1 data values the user gives to the script

***template.prn***

```
GK"image"
GM"image"1943
**binary data**
FK"data"
FS"data"
V00,99,N,""
V01,99,N,""
V02,99,N,""
GG204,89,"image"
b264,130,Q,m2,o2,sL,x8,y04,V00
b543,130,Q,m2,o2,sL,x8,y04,V04
b823,130,Q,m2,o2,sL,x8,y04,V08
A264,40,2,1,1,1,N,V02
A543,40,2,1,1,1,N,V06
A823,40,2,1,1,1,N,V10
A175,65,2,3,1,1,N,V01
A454,65,2,3,1,1,N,V05
A734,65,2,3,1,1,N,V09
A175,101,2,1,1,1,N,V03
A454,101,2,1,1,1,N,V07
A734,101,2,1,1,1,N,V11

FE
N

FR"info"
?
QR_CODE
value_0
value_1
value_2
N
P1
FK"info"
GK"image"
```

But it doesn't prints the image, just the data on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed my way to make it print an image (i'm not sure if this is the best way to do it)

---

1. Use BarTender to print serialized stickers (send the same numbers as columns available)

- This will convert your image into a x3 (in my case) image copy of your pic, and it will convert it into `.pcx`

2. Replace your data in your `.prn` manually or using `FS` and variables `V00`